# How do I stop VS Code Terminal in displaying autocompletion of everything?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, autocomplete

Recently got my self a new PC, didnt have the issue on the old one.
Installed VS Code, logged in to sync, and got all my extensions.

Issue at hand:
In Terminal, having typed:new-
will prompt in it showing[image]

I've tried starting VS Code without extensions with the "code --disable-extensions" command, but it still shows..

Does anyone know how to fix it? and only show autocompletion when I e.g. hit TAB or something. Right know it makes it kinda hard to see what I'm writing, as the text doesnt go away while i type other stuff..

---

Version: 1.87.1 (system setup)

Commit: 1e790d77f81672c49be070e04474901747115651

Date: 2024-03-06T00:21:36.258Z

Electron: 27.3.2

ElectronBuildId: 26836302

Chromium: 118.0.5993.159

Node.js: 18.17.1

V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

Comment: Hi @starball
As already mentioned at creation, I've tried starting VS Code without extensions, and the issue appeared there as well.
I Agree, something is really wrong with it..

Comment: When using "windows desktop powershell" or "powershell 7" it doesnt happened.
I've now tried reinstalling, same issue.
Then I disabled the "Enable Profile Loading" and added PS7 and the "Windows Desktop Powershell" to the "Additional exe paths" which seems to have fixed it within VS Code.

Comment: interesting... are you sure all of those changes in combination are necessary to fix this? or does only doing some smaller subset of them also fix it?

Comment: I tested after each setup, but didn’t change settings back before implementing the ps exe paths. Once the exe paths was in place it seemed to have fixed it. Perhaps because  a now starts the terminal as one of those